# hi.. How to make apps that use by user auto log out when the back-end deactivate or delete the user account?

Tags: android

I am developing Android. I success to make Android Application login and logout that set by user. But when i deactivate the account user at back-end side (using boilerplate), the android application that use by user not logout. What I must to do.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post what you have tried and try to be specific on your question.

Comment: use push notifications to send data from server to clicnt.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Service` that periodically check if the user is still valid. Along with that, you can check for the validity of the user when the user makes an action that access the server.

When the service or the action detects that the user is no longer valid. Then just bring the user back to the login page.

Example code of the `Service`

```
public class SessionService extends Service {

    private AtomicBoolean isStopped = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private static final long CHECK_EVERY = 1000L; // check every 1 second

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        // session checker thread
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                while (!isStopped.get()) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(CHECK_EVERY);

                        // ask API if user is still valid
                        boolean isUserValid = APIDao.isUserValid();
                        if (!isUserValid) { // user is no longer valid

                            // kill all Activity then open the LoginActivity
                            handler.post(new Runnable() { // runOnUiThread
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
                                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

        @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // stop the thread
        isStopped.set(true);
    }
}
```

There's one more thing I can think of, using Push Notification. I haven't tried this but basically the server can send a message to the app. This is ussually used by messenger apps.